# Im getting this error message from this particular piece of code

Tags: solidity

```
interface IERC20 {
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}
```

And along with this error i am recieving this error message

> This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.

what can i do to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deploy an interface, which is not possible because it doesn't contain any code - just definition of functions.

---

If you already have a contract that implements this interface, you need to select it in the "Deploy" tab, see the screnshot:

[image: Selecting contract to deploy]

---

If you haven't implemented the contract, you're in the very beginning and need to implement the whole thing to have a working ERC-20 token contract.

There is no "best way" to create an ERC-20 token, because each contract can be implemented differently but still implement the ERC-20 standard. For starters, I'd recommend reading the OpenZeppelin [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20) and their [source codes](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20) to see how they implement the standard. Or if you google "[minimal erc-20 contract](https://www.google.com/search?q=minimal%20erc-20%20contract)", you'll find few more implementations that might be easier to grasp.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract is IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        // TODO implement this function
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256) {
        // TODO implement this function
    }
    
    // TODO implement all functions of the interface
}
```